# How to teleport only unemployed villagers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How does one teleport only unemployed villagers in Minecraft 1.18.2 java edition?

I have tried the following:

```
tp @e[type=villager, nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:unemployed"}}, limit=2] Romans1234

tp @e[type=villager, nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:0"}}, limit=2] Romans1234

tp @e[type=villager, nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:none"}}, limit=2] Romans1234

tp @e[type=villager, nbt={VillagerData:{profession:""}}, limit=2] Romans1234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah for providing the link towards the Minecraft Villager professions. From there I was able to find the solution:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager, nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"Minecraft:none"}}] Romans1234
```

The fault in the code mentioned in the question, is that I forgot to add `minecraft:` to the `type` parameter.

The above code will teleport all villagers without a profession to a player named Romans1234.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is `profession:"minecraft:nitwit"`, as being unemployed is a kind of profession in the game, not absence of profession as you supposed.

Reference: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Villager_profession).

Comment: Hello. While the code you provided is correct, it does not answer the question. I do not want to teleport nitwits, I want to teleport a villager that does not currently have a profession. Thank you for the contribution though!

Comment: @Romans You're welcome.