# Is it possible to teleport an entity with a specific nbt but without filling it in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wanting to teleport entities that have a name, just like when you use tags to name a creature in Minecraft, and I wanted to teleport any and all entities that have a name, whatever it may be, is it possible to do this? would work as a filter, I teleport the entity that has a name, ignoring those that don't.

I tried different ways, but my knowledge is very vague, below are some examples.

/tp @e[type=!minecraft:player,name=""] @p

/tp @e[type=!minecraft:player,nbt={CustomName:""] @p

/tp @e[type=!minecraft:player,nbt={CustomName: '{"text":""}'}] @p

I'm currently testing on version 1.16.5

Comment: I guess you need a common denominator and filter using that (e.g. 'animal' or 'mob'). Have you looked through the existing questions here (like e.g. [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=teleport+without+name+minecraft))? [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397795/) might give you a solution, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can select entities that have a specific NBT tag, regardless of value, with `/execute`, like so.

```
/execute as <selector> if data entity @s <tag> run <command>
```

Replace `<selector>` with a selector for the entities you want to test, `<tag>` with the NBT tag to check for, and `<command>` with the command that will be run for every entity with the specified tag, as that entity.

For your specific example of teleporting all entities with a custom name to the player, this command should do what you want.

```
/execute as @e[type=!player] if data entity @s CustomName run tp @p
```